# Save HTML list with PHP to database

Tags: php, html, database, list, save

I was wondering if it is possible to save the data in an HTML list to a database. If so, can I do it with PHP and maybe how?

The reason I want to do so is, I have a javascript that can create lists in HTML. To the list there is a javascript, which makes it possible to drag and sort the list items if you want to do so. All the javascripts are independent of each other.

Now when I have placed my custom list items in the list I would like to be able to save them in the right order in a database. I just can't think of a way to do so, and is it even possible?

Remember that my list is an ordinary HTML `<ol></ol>`/`<ul></ul>` -list.

Comment: not the best idea to save html in the database for this purpose. Instead store a proper representation of your data. For example JSON. Then retrieve the data on your client side and build up the html from the data you just retrieved.

Comment: Thank you for that fast response. I will definitely look into that.

Answer (score 0):

in your database create a column called sequence, or seq, and make it a number.

so now your database has an item and a number.    Ford,1:   Chevy,2: and so on....

```
 <ol>

<?php

 $select = "SELECT carModel from cars order by sequence";
 $qry = $db->query($select);
 while($row = $qry->fetch())
 {
     echo "<li>" . $row['carModel'] . "</li>";
 }
?>
 </ol>
```

this will give you results in a list ordered by whatever seq you have.